# Overflow-x doesn't work with absolutely positioned divs

Tags: html, css, position

So I am creating a slideshow and I am facing a problem. I have some divs, which positions are absolute and I give `left: 100%;` to them. This nicely works on full screen, but when I resize the screen absolute position breaks `overflow-x: hidden;` given to `body` and `html` tags. How to fix this?

Here is the code

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slides {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}

.slide-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#slide-2 {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Marseille</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slides" id="slide-1">
    <img class="slide-img" src="media/slideshow/image-1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slides" id="slide-2">
    <img class="slide-img" src="media/slideshow/image-2.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slides" id="slide-3">
    <img class="slide-img" src="media/slideshow/image-3.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="slides" id="slide-4">
    <img class="slide-img" src="media/slideshow/image-4.jpg">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In what way does your overflow break?  It's not very clear what your problem is

Comment: @Pete, when I resize the screen using, inspect, the div with left: 100%; appears on screen instead of staying out of the screen

Comment: Your above code seems to work fine for me - the div is always off the screen

Comment: https://attempt-marseille.000webhostapp.com/ - Just open this via mobile phone and you will get the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `left` parameter for *all four* (or actually three) absolutely positioned DIVs, other wise DIV #3 and 4 will (which still have `left: 0`) be shown inside the viewport and cover DIV #1.
In the snippet below I set the left paramter to 25/50/75% for DIVs 2-4 to demonstrate that it works (you need to set those to at least 100% or more, depending on how you slide them into the viewport).

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slides {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}

.slide-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#slide-2 {
  left: 25%;
}
#slide-3 {
  left: 50%;
}
#slide-4 {
  left: 75%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="slides" id="slide-1">
    <img class="slide-img" src="http://placehold.it/800x500/fb8">
  </div>
  <div class="slides" id="slide-2">
    <img class="slide-img" src="http://placehold.it/700x500/bf8">
  </div>
  <div class="slides" id="slide-3">
    <img class="slide-img" src="http://placehold.it/900x500/8bf">
  </div>
  <div class="slides" id="slide-4">
    <img class="slide-img" src="http://placehold.it/600x500/f8b">
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't need to show all the divs. I want to show only the first one. but when I resize the screen using inspect, I get them all on the screen. I need to show only one and my problem is that the second one is shown on smaller screens, too.

Comment: I have done just as you have written but I still have the problem. It really works well on the full screen, the problem is only with smaller screens.